# How to determine user has come though login page or sso page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two pages in my application.

One is for Login User say `Default.asp` and
Other for SingleSignon say `sso.aspx`

If the user comes through the single sign on and session expires to redirected to `Default.aspx` where user can enter username and password and click login.

I want to show different panel on default.aspx page if user comes though SSO page.

I tried to created cookies but know success. As I have to check cookies on the page load and also set it on page load and hide the panel accordingly.

Can I use `Session_Start` and check and set a cookie weather it is coming from SSO page or default page or there is a different way of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

As you are using the ASP.NET you can use the following two options in Page Load. 
Option : 1
`Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]`
Although note on the above it is possible for browsers to block the value (empty value).

Option : 2
You can check the `Request.UrlReferrer` of the current `HttpRequest`: it will usually contain the page from where the user is coming from (depends on the browser, though).

Reference:
[how do I determine where the user came from in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166113/how-do-i-determine-where-the-user-came-from-in-asp-net)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Session_Start event is not suitable for these kind of things. Session_start runs when a user first enters in your applications, think it like the first page load.

You can use a query string parameter to determine where the user redirected from.

For example, if user redirected from sso.aspx to default.aspx, use url like that :

default.aspx?previouspage=sso

then, check the previouspage query string parameter at default.aspx, to show or hide your panel.

Comment: I agree but if I check the requested page and set the cookie accordingly. And if I check it on Default page load will it work?

Comment: @शेखर : Yes it will work. But you need to clear that cookie correctly, if it persists user will see your panel always visible. Also think about browsers with disabled cookies.

Comment: Just ignore them -- any browser that has session cookies disabled can't log in anyhow.